# PHP Mysqli SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE from different databases

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, insert

I am trying to select values from one DB. And insert and update the result into another. This is cronjob that needs to run everyday to replicate some data from one DB into another. I know I am missing steps / correct syntax, but I hope someone can help me out.

```
<?php

    $con_1=mysqli_connect("host","user","pw","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $con_2=mysqli_connect("host","user","pw","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con_1,"SELECT id, name FROM table GROUP BY 1,2");

    $mysqli->query($con_2, "INSERT INTO `table2`(`id`, `name`) VALUES ('".$result[1]."', ".$result[2].") 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = ".$result[2]."");

    }

    mysqli_close($con_1);
    mysqli_close($con_2);
    ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are executing SQL but not checking to see if it was successful. Add this in after you get your `$result`. Check the PHP docs to see what `mysqli_query` returns in the case of an error (I believe it will be `false`).

Comment: use try catch with transactions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html for more safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query` returns a query object, using `$result[1]` doesn't make sense, you need to fetch the rows in a loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // insert result in second database
}
```

For other access methods check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.summary.php).

Comment: @JurienGroot it's hard to read form the comment, you probably should ask another question and better explain your problem.

Comment: yes, something went wrong. Sorry about that. I tried to make mysql_affected_rows to work, but didn't succeed. Your answer to the current question worked well though. Thanks